# didSelectRowAtIndexPath or prepareForSegue to use?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, if-statement

i want to be able to select a item in my tableview and get to the correct view.
say i have two items in my uitableview. one has a value of ubuntu other has a value of arch- in my plist from arraA i have a SystemID which holds the text Ubuntu/Arch, never both

now when i select the one with ubuntu i want it to push to a new view where ubuntu stuff is
and if i go back and select arch it will again push me to a view where arch stuff is

so far i made this and it's not working as intended:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *segueName = nil;

if ([[arrayA valueForKey:@"SystemID"]isEqualToString:@"Ubuntu Linux"]) {
    ActionViewController *controller = [[ActionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Ubuntu Linux" bundle:nil];
    controller.Serverinfo = [arrayA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
else if ([[arrayA valueForKey:@"SystemID"]isEqualToString:@"Arch Linux"]) {
    ActionViewController *controller = [[ActionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Arch Linux" bundle:nil];
    controller.Serverinfo = [arrayA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}

[self performSegueWithIdentifier: segueName sender: self];
}
```

also tried prepare forsegue

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if([arrayA valueForKey:@"Arch Linux"])
{
    ActionViewController *controller = (ActionViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.mainTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    controller.Serverinfo = [arrayA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"hostname = %@", controller.Serverinfo);
}
if ([arrayA valueForKey:@"Ubuntu Linux"]) {
    ActionViewController *controller = (ActionViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.mainTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    controller.Serverinfo = [arrayA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"hostname = %@", controller.Serverinfo);
}
}
```

arrayA is a NSMutableArray that read from a plist that you can see here
[image]
[image: nib]

Comment: Is an arrayA type of NSArray or NSMutableArray? Do you keep in arrayA two object of type NSString?

Comment: I think you need use `indexPath` or `sender` in this code to know which row is selected.

Comment: arrayA is a NSMutableArray. two objects with different values

Comment: @KennyVB what kind of objects are stored in arrayA?

Comment: @Greg nsstrings "text". i updated the question so you can see what it have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your method to:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if ([arrayA[indexPath.row][@"SystemID"]isEqualToString:@"Ubuntu Linux"]) {
    //ActionViewController *controller = [[ActionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Ubuntu Linux" bundle:nil];
    // Make sure you replace Storyboard with your storyboard name
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
    ActionViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Ubuntu Linux"];
    controller.Serverinfo = [arrayA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
else if ([arrayA[indexPath.row][@"SystemID"]isEqualToString:@"Arch Linux"]) {
    ActionViewController *controller = [[ActionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Arch Linux" bundle:nil];
    controller.Serverinfo = [arrayA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
}
```

You don't need to call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier: segueName sender: self];` in didSelectRow because you already push your view in didSelectRow method. If you call it you puts the view twice.

Comment: i tried using your code. how ever it can't find the NIB ? i updated my question to reflect what my nib is called. starting to get little confused if i named it the right place

Comment: i think i need to make it into a storyboard id somehow with that code you posted. can you help with that ? thx so much so far. or i could just create a nib actually.

Comment: @KennyVB You have to load your view controller from storyboard. See example for Ubuntu Linux and apply the logic for Arch Linux.

Comment: B-E-A-UTIFUL ! how ever. when i go back it crashes now ?

Comment: @KennyVB remove prepareForSegue: method. if you need it add if identifier check.

Comment: removed it. now i only have what you wrote of code and adjusted it to fits the names of my storyboard and so on. how ever i get this nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
2014-01-11 15:33:46.909 LinuxManagement[4779:70b] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted. and when i go back i can click go back twice then it crashes with this Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't add self as subview'

Comment: got it to work now. had to make a separate plist file :) thanks for all the help. i'll get codeing

Comment: @KennyVB have you got any segue (connection in storyboard) from your table view to ActionViewController? If you have one delete it.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Ooh boy, you're off in the weeds.

First, stop talking about pushing a "view." The term view and view controller are **NOT interchangeable**. A view is an object that appears on the screen. A view CONTROLLER is an object that manages a collection of views (usually the entire screen.)

You push a view controller, not a view. The view controller then displays it's content view on the screen.

Now, as to your code.

The if statement in your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method is messed up.

```
if ([[arrayA valueForKey:@"SystemID"]isEqualToString:@"Ubuntu Linux"])
```

You don't want to use `valueForeKey` on an array. That method attempts to call `valueForKey` on every object in your array, and what it returns is an array of the results.

Arrays are indexed by a numeric index, not a key. You want an array as the data source for a table view.

What you want to do is to fetch the object at your selected row from your array.

In order to help you further, though, you need to explain what you have stored in your arrayA. Is it an array of dictionaries? An array of strings?

Also, you are mixing NIB based view controller code with storyboard code. You can certainly use both in the same program if you need to, but as a beginner you probably should not.

In your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method you're creating a view controller with `initWithNibName`, pushing it, and then calling `performSegueWithIdentifier`. You want to do one or the other, not both.

Comment: soo teach me or point me in a direction on what i should use and how to make it work properly.... because as of now. i'm lost

Comment: Kenny, Greg's answer gives you everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use storyboard with `prepareForSegue`